# ¿Cómo permitir/denegar acceso a todas las vista de una aplicación según el grupo de usuario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-urls

En mi archivo `urls.py` principal, tengo las siguientes rutas:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('apps.index.urls')),
    path('mecanica/', include('apps.mecanica.urls')),
    path('electronica/', include('apps.electronica.urls')),
    path('carpinteria/', include('apps.carpinteria.urls')),
]
```

A su vez, dentro del archivo `urls.py` de cada aplicación, `mecanica`, `electronica` y `carpinteria`, están las rutas para listar, agregar, modificar y eliminar los correspondiente registros.

**Aquí empieza la duda**

Dado 3 grupos de usuarios, llamados `mecanicos`, `electronicos` y `carpinteros`, ¿Cuál es la forma apropiada para controlar el acceso a las vistas de cada aplicación, en función del grupo al que pertenece el usuario?

Ejemplo, usuarios del grupo `electronicos` solo pueden acceder a las rutas *`electronica/list`*, *`electronica/add`*, *`electronica/edit`* ... pero no a las rutas *`mecanica/list`*, *`mecanica/add`*, *`carpinteria/list`*, *`carpinteria/add`*..., en ese caso, debería re direccionar a otra ruta, por ejemplo al de la aplicación `index`.

**Por último**
Todos los usuarios son creados con el modelo `User` de Django y se crean desde el administrador

```
django.contrib.auth.models.User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya que estas usando grupos y solo te interesa que solo puedan acceder a las views los usuarios de cierto grupo, considero la manera mas sencilla y limpiamente posible de hacerlo es con un decorador, estos alteran la funcionalidad de una función, método, clase, etc sin necesidad de que modifiques internamente cada función. Tienes decoradores como @login_required en el cual no te deja acceder a un view si no estas logeado, pero para este caso es necesario crear uno propio que verifique el grupo al que pertenece el usuario y así dejarlo acceder o no al view.

Para esto primero tienes que definir un decorator, como lo vas a usar en varios lados dentro de alguna de tus apps crea un archivo que se llame decorators.py y dentro de este crearas la siguiente función:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test


def group_required(*group_names):
   """ Evalua si el usuario pertenece a alguno de los grupos indicados."""

   def in_groups(u):
       if u.is_authenticated():
           if bool(u.groups.filter(name__in=group_names)) | u.is_superuser:
               return True
       return False
   return user_passes_test(in_groups)
```

Una vez hecho esto, si estas usando FBV para utilizar el decorador es de la siguiente manera:

```
@login_required
@group_required('mecanicos',)
def vista_mecanicos(request, pk)
    ...
```

Primero checas que el usuario haya iniciado sesión y después ves si pertenece al grupo 'mecanicos'

Si estas usando un CBV se utiliza de estas maneras:

```
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'

    decorators = [login_required, group_required('mecanicos',)]
    @method_decorator(decorators )
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

O de esta manera:

```
decorators = [login_required, group_required('mecanicos',)]
@method_decorator(decorators, name='dispatch')
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'
```

o tambien:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(group_required('mecanicos',), name='dispatch')
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'
```

Esto ultimo lo puedes ver aca: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

Comment: **Solo una observación**, en la línea `if u.is_authenticated():` no corresponden los paréntesis `()`. Tengo entendido que `is_authenticated` es un atributo del modelo `User`, por lo tanto no es invocable como una función. Por lo demás, esta bien.

Comment: Así es tienes toda la razón, en versiones anteriores a Django 2 todavía se llamaba como método, a partir de la versión 2 en adelante ya se usa como atributo. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.0/